# Low-cost video streaming distribution system

Tags: linux, video, open-source, video-streaming, network-camera

I work at an animal shelter.  We want to mount one or more network "kitty cams" or "puppy cams", so that visitors to our website can view live video streaming of our animals.  Our upstream bandwidth is only about 3 or 4 Mbps, so we need to have some kind of video distribution system in place.  Of course, there are companies that will do this for you, but for a hefty fee.  See, for example, http://www.dacast.com/live-streaming-media.html .

We can probably get a local company to give us a discount on a co-located server or maybe a virtual private server.  What sort of system would I need to implement on the server in order to set up the live streaming service?  And is this approach even practical? I have no experience in this area.  Open-source (i.e., free) tools are much preferred, given our limited budget for this project.  Here's one possibility I found using Google, but I'm really not certain that his would fulfill the intended function: https://code.google.com/p/baus/

Answer (score 1):

How about use [Justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv)?

I haven't followed the site for a couple years, but last I knew you could broadcast a live webcam stream for free. All you would need is a webcam (or webcams) and justin.tv loaded on a web browser. It also allows users to view history of the live stream. Maybe you can embed the stream into your website?

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  The free version of Justin.tv includes advertisements.    I would prefer to have a "clean" video stream embedded in our site.  The premium (ad-free) plans are actually fairly expensive: http://www.justin.tv/payments/premium/ .  Still, if I can't find a solution to implement myself, I may have to use the ad-based option.